# View.Gone not removing space for linearlayout

Tags: android

I am making my LinearLayout view View.Gone but still it takes the space and empty space is shown.
Please help me.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tvshow_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:paddingLeft="14dp"
            android:paddingRight="14dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:shadowColor="@color/RGB_100_220_220_220"
                android:shadowDx="1"
                android:shadowDy="1"
                android:shadowRadius="2"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/common_title_tvshows"
                android:textColor="@color/RGB_100_5_5_5"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/common_button_arrow_left"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_detail_next_devider" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/common_button_arrow_right"
                    android:clickable="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="147dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <com.sec.msc.android.yosemite.ui.detailview.HorizontalListAdapterView
                android:id="@+id/nestedlistview_tv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </RelativeLayout>



    </LinearLayout>
```

Inside the getView method of listview which is having this linearlayout as the row,I am doing this

```
holder.movielayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvshow_layout);
holder.tvshowlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

 ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null){

            convertView = Inflater.inflate(mLayout, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.movielayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.seasonalfavorites_movie_layout);
            holder.tvshowlayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.seasonalfavorites_tvshow_layout);
            holder.nestedMovieList = (HorizontalListAdapterView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.nestedlistview_movie);
            holder.nestedTvList = (HorizontalListAdapterView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.nestedlistview_tv);


            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

            String title = mPromotionList.get(position).getPromotionTitle();    
            holder.titleText.setText(title);
            movieItemList = (ArrayList<SeasonalFavoritesListItem>) mMovieMap.get(title);
            tvItemList = (ArrayList<SeasonalFavoritesListItem>) mTvShowMap.get(title);
            if(tvItemList.size()>0){
                holder.tvshowlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                SeasonalFavoritesHorizentalListAdapter listAdaptrTv = new SeasonalFavoritesHorizentalListAdapter(mContext,tvItemList,1,holder.nestedTvList);
                holder.nestedTvList.setAdapter(listAdaptrTv);
            }else{
                holder.tvshowlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            if(movieItemList.size()>0){
                holder.movielayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                SeasonalFavoritesHorizentalListAdapter listAdaptr = new SeasonalFavoritesHorizentalListAdapter(mContext,movieItemList,0,holder.nestedMovieList);
                holder.nestedMovieList.setAdapter(listAdaptr);
            }else{
                holder.movielayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
```

Comment: you must be imposing some condition please share your getView method Code.

Comment: updated the question with getView

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Are you trying to remove an item in your ListView?

Comment: i want to remove one part of the item in my list view.there are two parts 1.movie 2.tvshows.The same layout is applicable for movies also if the list is empty then corresponding layout i want to hide

Comment: Clarification.  You want to hide it from the screen, but still have it be part of the layout, right?

Comment: the layout is hidden but still taking the space.in short View.Gone acting like View.Invisible

Comment: I wonder if you call invalidate() on the parent view if that will force the layout to be recalculated.

Comment: thanks for your comment.still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem.My parent layout was having background image which was taking the space.Once i changed that it worked fine